# Autostart Resilio Sync Script in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: scripts, autostart, btsync

I am trying to configure a script (Resilio Sync) to start every time I boot up, I tried crontab @reboot but this seems to only work on reboots, not when booting cold. I tried adding Resilio Sync in gnome tweaks (I use Ubuntu Gnome) but since it's a script, it does not seem to have a .desktop file associated with it.

Is the only way I can start the script on boot-up to create a .desktop file which I then integrate via tweak tools into startup? Or is there maybe a less cumbersome way to achieve my goal?

Best,
Berliny

Comment: Not familiar withb Resilio Sync,, bur as far as I understand, the script needs to run on user level. Simply add it to Startup Applications (Dash > Startup Applications). The .desktop file is then automatically made for you and put in the right place (`~/.config/autostart`).

Comment: Not sure whether I did it correctly, but it does not seem to work. I used the command /path/to/resiliosync/rslsync.sh or should I have used ./path/to/resiliosync/rslsync.sh or bash /... I'm confused I feel like I made it work once but cannot remember how?

Comment: what is normally the (working) command you use to run the script?

Comment: ...Anyway, it depends on if the script is executable or not, has the shebang etc.

Comment: ./rslsync.sh or clicking on it after setting it as executable

Comment: ...That one won't work, since a .desktop file does not know where you are. Do you need to be in the working directory, or are paths inside the script absolute?

Comment: That's beyond me, since you can copy the containing folder into any directory and it still works, I guess the paths are designed to be independent of the location of the script?